# Why is my method which should simply return the highest value in an array not working?

Tags: java, methods

I have an int array `tmax[]`, which is defined in my `main` method, and an `arrayMax` method which is defined within the same class but not the `main` function

excerpt from `main`:

```
int maximumTemp = arrayMax(tmax[]);
```

function `arrayMax`:

```
public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];

    return max; 
}
```

for some reason I get 3 error messages on the line for defining `maximumTemp`:

- `Syntax error, insert ".class" to complete ArgumentList`
- `The method (arrayMax(int[])) in the type Weather //which is my class name// is not applicable for the arguments (Class <tmax[]>)`
- `tmax cannot be resolved to a type`

here's the whole code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Weather {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int a;
        
        File weatherData = new File("C:\\Users\\taddi\\eclipse-workspace\\COS_160_ASSIGNMENT_10\\src\\PortlandWeather1941to2018.txt");

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(weatherData);
        scnr.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[/\\s]+"));
        
        int totalCount = scnr.nextInt();// this reads the number at the beginning and uses it so I know how many times to run the loop
        String throwAway1 = scnr.nextLine();//these statement are used to throw a way the rest of line 1, and all of line 2 and 3
        String throwAway2 = scnr.nextLine();
        String throwAway3 = scnr.nextLine();
        
        int[] month = new int[totalCount];
        int[] day = new int[totalCount];
        int[] year = new int[totalCount];
        
        int[] tmax = new int[totalCount];
        int[] tmin = new int[totalCount];
        
        System.out.println(totalCount);
        for (a = 0; a < totalCount; a ++) {
            month[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.print(month[a] + " ");
            
            day[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.print(day[a] + " ");
             
            year[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.print(year[a]);
            
            
            tmax[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.print(tmax[a]);
            
        
            tmin[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(tmin[a]);
        }
        
        int maximumTemp = arrayMax(tmax[]);
    }
    
    public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] > max)
                max = a[i];

        return max; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: It's not that your code isn't "working" but rather that it doesn't compile, a completely different issue. Please show more of the code and the full error message.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/RoJXMp).

Comment: Not `int maximumTemp = arrayMax(tmax[]);` but rather `int maximumTemp = arrayMax(tmax);` do you see the difference? You pass in the array variable into the method, without the empty brackets. Your compilation error is a typographical error.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. It's hard to believe I was staring at it the whole time and didn't notice it.